# One direction data binding on resused components

Tags: angular

[image]

Both **Block1** and **Block2** are same component "`hello.component.ts`"(reused component)
Whatever data updating from **Block1** *input box* should reflect on **Block2** *input box*.

But the data updating from **Block2** to **Block1** should not update.

The data should update one direction, there is no multi-directional.

Currently data updating on multi-direction, difficult to get solution on this.

Please give short solution.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ctgaek)

Comment: As per the updated stackblitz link above, -In First Component, once the value changes in input text, ngModelChange assigned method get called and emit the updated value through output decorator and value get assigned.
-In Second Component, we don't have any output decorator, so value not updated, it remains only within the component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see it being "multi-directional", because you're passing the same object reference to both components.

Replace that with a simple string and use inputs/outputs, like this:

```
// hello.component.ts
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
  <input type="text" [ngModel]="name" (ngModelChange)="updateName($event)" />
  <h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>
  `,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() name: any;
  @Output() nameChanged: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();

  updateName(name: string): void {
    this.name = name;
    this.nameChanged.emit(name);
  }
}

// app.component.html
<p> Block1</p>
<hello [name]="name" (nameChanged)="name = $event"></hello>
<p> Block2</p>
<hello [name]="name"></hello>

// app.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
}
```